# Question about '' inset faces''

Tags: modeling

I am trying to inset a face with 12 edges, however when i do so, i get weird geometry.

What am i doing wrong ?

See pic

[image]

Comment: Seems like you accidentally lock the z transform in inset operation

Answer (score 1):

Apply scale with CTRL+A before the insect face

Comment: i am trying. but doesnt seem to make a difference

Comment: Oops, overlapped. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Its diffcult to tell from the underlying mesh what you have. It looks like this:

[image]

If that is correct then when you inset faces <kbd>I</kbd> I get this

[image]

However, the image with the green arrows has this:

[image]

which looks like different topology.

If you can show it before the inset faces and also check for duplicates by doing a merge by distance <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>

also show the values you used on the inset faces panel after the operation

Comment: thank you for your reply, this is how it looks before i insert faces. https://imgur.com/a/u87zqrr

Answer (score 0):

It could be this: (reading left to right, top to bottom)

[image]...

1. Circle, as created
2. Scaled in Object mode, 0.5 in Y, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> scale applied This is now the 'true mesh'.
3. Scaled in Object mode, by 2 in Y. It *looks* like a circle mesh. But it isn't. It's an oval mesh with an object-level transformation matrix, which scales it in Y.
4. Inset. The inset operates on the **underlying mesh** (2), insetting it evenly, and *then* the object-level transform scales it in Y, which makes it uneven.

In other words, you might have to apply the scale of your object.

Comment: thanks for your reply, however i created a cylinder with 12 vertices via Mesh > Cylinder > Ngon cap, just like the guy in this tutorial did https://youtu.be/WFzIbz2FN28?t=447

Comment: @Rachquiat    OK.. could be wrong.. in Object mode, just hit N to bring up the Properties region, 'Item' tab, 'Transform' panel, and confirm the scale is 1 in X,Y and Z.

Comment: thank you very much! that was the problem. i found that my object deformed because it was grouped with the object above it (i think becuase i used the curser to draw from that object). gracias!!!